# Как сверстать галерею картинок?

Tags: html, css

Исходные картинки разной высоты и ширины. Лучше через `background-image` каждому блоку сделать? Но ведь тогда будет много классов, для каждого `background-image`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Пример

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    clear: both;
}

.gallery__item {
    background: #737373;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.gallery__img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery__item">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__item">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/arch" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__item">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/nature" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__item">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/340/640/people" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__item">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/750/1000/people" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__item">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/500/tech" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавлю пожалуй, что `object-fit` не поддерживается IE.

Comment: @Игорь - для кроссбраузерности можно использовать polyfill - https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images

Comment: @Игорь, кому сдался этот IE..

Comment: @soledar10, спасибо, не знал.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете задать один класс на все элементы слайда, а сами картинки подключить через style:

```
<div class="slide-image" style="background-image: url(your_link);"></div>
```

И в CSS:

```
.slide-image {
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
width: 100px; //Ширина блока слайда
height: 100px; //Высота блока слайда
}
```

Comment: а может другой способ? инлайновые стили наверное не хорошо

Comment: @Stepan Ivanov, если пихать всё подряд через style - да, нехорошо. А в этом случае это единственный более менее адекватный вариант, да и гибкий, если использовать что-нибудь для автоматизации добавления слайдов.

Comment: Что можно использовать, например?